# Push git changes to a shared network drive

Tags: git, networking, push, shared, drive

How can a team of four people use Git (specifically [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/)) to push local changes to a shared network drive?

Right now (without Git) we have to copy the files from the network drive to our local machine, edit the files, and then re-upload them to the shared network drive. This is a painstaking process that can lead to lots of errors, but it seems like something Git could help us with.

Can we simply install Git on the shared drive and go from there?

Answer (score 143):

Not sure if you found something that works for you or not, but I have a writeup on how to do that very thing on a windows network drive:

http://tony.halcyonlane.com/blog/2011/09/22/Using-git-at-work-on-a-Windows-network-drive/

From a cmd prompt change to your mapped drive.

> $ cd g:

Then cd into your soon to be git repository.

> $ cd scripts

Then create an empty git repository. If you do not use the --bare option, you will have issues so don't leave that out.

> $ git init --bare

Now if you don't have a local git repository yet, then you can clone your new repository wherever you like by navigating back to your local drive.

> $ c:
>
> $ cd work/scripts
>
> $ git clone file://g:\scripts

When you clone, you automatically get a remote called "origin" and you can push to the server for safe keeping any time you make changes locally.

> $ git push origin master

If you already have a git repository and you just want to push out to the shared drive then you can do this from within your local git dir.

> $ git remote add origin file://g:\scripts
>
> $ git push origin master

Comment: Thank you -- I did exactly this for a personal project on my home network.

Comment: I followed these steps but get the following errors when I run git push origin master 
error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

Comment: Thank you.  Took a long time to find this answer

Comment: For anyone who doesn't have their shared drive mapped, there's pushd (and popd) to create a virtual temp drive to navigate to ([see link](https://superuser.com/a/399885))

Comment: can I put //192.168.1.1/shared/folder/repobare.git instead of the mapped G:\scripts?

Comment: shouldn't you create a directory `.git` within `scripts/` ?

Comment: For anyone who gets the error '...No such file or directory...', try mapping a network drive past the folder(s) you don't have access to. Git tries to search parent directories

Comment: This works fine. However, when calling `git status` on the shared folder after `git init --bare` I get the following error: `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'shared_drive'`. I know I can silence this error related to me not being the owner of the shared folder, and then work normally. But I am wondering whether that will cause any issues in the long run (Note: I am the only developer who usually modifies scripts in these shared folders)

Answer (score 27):

Our team currently does exactly this. Every developer has the following:

1. Git installed on their local machine
2. Access to their own personal shared drive (`L:`)
3. Access to a shared group drive (`V:`)

We have the "remote" repository (set up using `init -bare`) on the `V:` drive, and everyone has a clone on their personal `L:` drive. All changes are made to the `L:` drive and pushed up to the `V:` drive, which are then pulled down later by the other developers to their respective personal repositories on their `L:` drives. This works without any problems, and mitigates the need for a Git server.

Comment: Okay, great! Do I need to first create a local repo, and then set up a remote of that repo on the shared drive?

Comment: @user1549303 - That's how we do it. You can create the local repo (our `L:` drive repo) using `git init`, and then create the remote (our `v:` drive one) using `git clone --bare` (or a `git init --bare`, and then a push from the `L:`).

Comment: @eykanal - My Team currently uses an ancient, horrible source control library and we are looking to switch to git. One thing our current library lets me do is see who has checked out a file but forgot to check in the changes.  With git, all repositories are local, so how can you know if someone forgot to push to "v:"?

Comment: @KevinBuchan - I suggest you post your comment as a new question.

Comment: Ho does Git react when two developers try to push to the same shared repository (say V:) at the same time? Have you had any problem with concurrent push operations?

Comment: @Jordi - It's a simple race condition, first user wins. [Longer answer on this specific topic over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644294/168775).

Answer (score 2):

You can add another remote pointing to your network drive [(git remote)](http://gitref.org/remotes/)

Then you can push pull similar to what you do with github

Comment: The link target is no longer valid, can you update the link please ?