# Merging on git local shared drive

Tags: git, version-control

I am looking to implement a very basic version control at work with a team of 3 developers. I am looking to implement the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15487443/8876747 where we would have our own local repositories, make changes and push onto the shared drive. My only concern is overwriting.

What do I do in the case where we are working on the same piece of code/excel file (anything within the folder in general?) I assume if we just push our changes separately it will overwrite the first push, or the second push won't go through at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a single repository to simplify merging of files. The [Gitflow branching model](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) is really easy to use and scales to any number of developers.

You can set up a free hosted repository on Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc.

Comment: Isn't the outcome the same though? What's the difference between having the repository on GitHub versus just using a local one on a shared drive and pushing it onto there

Comment: Using a hosted repository requires less setup and maintenance than if you were to put it on a shared drive. It will also make it easy to view and resolve merge conflicts on a nice UI